# How to use ng-repeat and filter to hide some columns in a dynamic table?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a dynamic data set returned from a database for which I am trying to create a generic table that can always list it, no matter the number of columns or rows.

It works fine but the problem I am having is that I want to be able to hide some columns, like the ID for example.

This is how the data looks like:

```
scope.columns = [
    {
        'Name': 'ID',
        Visible: false,
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Name',
        Visible: true,
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Description',
        Visible: true,
    },
];

scope.rows = [
    {
        ID: 1, // should be hidden because ID column above is set to Visible - false
        Name: 'Test',
        Description: 'Its a test',
    },
    {
        ID: 2, // should be hidden because ID column above is set to Visible - false
        Name: 'Test 2',
        Description: 'Its a test 2',
    }
];
```

And this is `HTML` for the `table` generation:

```
<table class="table">
    <!-- This part works fine and doesn't show some of the columns -->
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns | filter: { Visible: 'true'}">
            <span ng-bind="column.Name"></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row"> <!-- This is the part where I need filter the cols based on the column.Visible above -->
            {{col}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried adding a filter on the `<td>` but I am not sure how to filter based on the `scope.columns` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `ng-if` -> `ng-if="columns[$index].Visible"` in your case like in this **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cwohnhgb/)**. Your attribute order  in `$scope.rows` must be the same as in `$scope.columns` to ensure it is working correct.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <!-- This part works fine and doesn't show some of the columns -->
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in columns | filter: { Visible: true}">
        <span ng-bind="column.Name"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="col in row" ng-if="columns[$index].Visible">
        {{col}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. I completely forgot about `$index`

Comment: @Apostrofix glad to help ya.